# How to go about making a "Sorted Array to Balanced BST" recursion algorithm to an iterative one?

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, stack

I've searched around but can't really understand or find help, since this iterative algorithm will require two stacks (to contain a left_Index and right_Index).

The main recursive way involves having it one side until the left_Index >= right_Index, and recursively doing so for both sides and per subsection (if that makes sense), which I don't understand how to do so exactly since I'm maintaining two stacks and need to see how exactly they relate to one another.

This problem is mostly due to me not understanding the way the normal recursive method words, although when looking at them side by side to see how to approach it, I always get stuck on what to do.

---

The backstory as to why I'm doing this:
Trying to solve the word ladder problem to go from A to B and decided to make a BST where the connections are connected by singular character differences and lengths. I'm getting the words from a text file containing a lot of the dictionary, and since I'm using a BST as the master list with all vertices the fact that this is a dictionary means every insert will be in order so the tree is right-leaning (so the speeds are slow for inserting O(n^2) which is a *big* hinderance). I was planning on storing data in an array then making a balanced BST from that since I believe speeds should go faster since insertion will be O(n*logn) which seems great. The problem with that is that I can't use a recursive approach since there's a lot of data leading to stack overflows, so I need to make it iteratively with stacks and loops, but am finding it too difficult.

---

My bad attempt at a start:

> while (lindx.the_front() < rindx.the_back())
>     {
>      mid =(lindx.the_front() + rindx.the_back()) / 2;
>      dictionary.addVertex(vector[mid]);
>      std::cout << "Pushed " << vector[mid] << '\n'; 
>      rindx.push(mid - 1);
>      }

---

That basically gets the 1/2's from the left half of the program from a linked stack I made. "the_front()" is the first insertion, "the_back()" is the final/latest insert into the list. The main problem I have is understanding how to make it repeat per half to get all the values.

---

I need to find my past homework where I've done this but the code is something along the lines of...

```
void array2balanced(int array[], int lIndex, int rIndex) 
{  
  //base case
  if(lIndex > rIndex) 
  {
    return; 
  } 
  //recursive cals
  else 
  {  
    mid = (lIndex+rIndex)/2;  
    tree.insert(array[mid]);  
    array2balanced(array, lIndex, mid-1);  
    array2balanced(array, mid+1, rIndex); 
  } 
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**
*Progress so far*

```
void balancedTree(std::vector<std::string> vector, dictionaryGraph &dictionary) // divide and conquer into tree?
{
    linkedStack<int> lindx, rindx, midX;
    unsigned int l_Index{ 0 }, r_Index{ vector.size() - 1 }, mid{ (l_Index + r_Index) / 2 };;
    lindx.push(l_Index);
    rindx.push(r_Index);
    midX.push(mid);
    int testCount{ 0 };
    std::cout << "There are " << vector.size() << " words.\n";

    while (!midX.empty())
    {
        mid = midX.pop();
        l_Index = lindx.pop();
        r_Index = rindx.pop();
        std::cout << "inputted " << vector[mid] << '\n';
        dictionary.addVertex(vector[mid]);
        testCount++;

        if (r_Index > l_Index)
        {

            midX.push((l_Index + mid) / 2);
            lindx.push(l_Index);
            rindx.push(mid - 1);
        }
        if (l_Index < r_Index)
        {
            midX.push((mid + r_Index) / 2);
            lindx.push(mid + 1);
            rindx.push(r_Index);
        }
    }
    std::cout << testCount << " words were inputted...\n"; // To see how many were inserted
    system("pause");
}
```

Problem I have is some inputs get repeated and some missed.

Comment: Could you post the pseudocode for the recursive algorithm you've seen?

Comment: 1) Get the Middle of the array and make it root.
2) Recursively do same for left half and right half.
      a) Get the middle of left half and make it left child of the root
          created in step 1.
      b) Get the middle of right half and make it right child of the
          root created in step 1.

- geeksforgeeks.org

Comment: It's a preorder traversal, so what you want is a variant of the iterative preorder traversal algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) but where you stack the positions together with the nodes.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having trouble though since my implementation isn't working, (since some indexes are missed and some repeated) but I'm getting close I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need two stacks. You just need either a one stack or one queue.
Below codes can be tested on [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-sorted-array-to-binary-search-tree/)

## Definition for a binary tree node.

```
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
```

## One Stack Method

```
def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums: List[int]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
    if not nums:
        return None
    l = len(nums)
    node = TreeNode(0)
    head = node
    s = collections.deque([(node, 0, l)])
    while s:
        node, left, right = s.pop()
        mid = (right + left) // 2
        node.val = nums[mid]
        if mid < right-1:
            node.right = TreeNode(0)
            s.append((node.right, mid+1, right))
        if left < mid:
            node.left = TreeNode(0)
            s.append((node.left, left, mid))
    return head
```

## One Queue Method

```
def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums: List[int]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
    if not nums:
        return None
    l = len(nums)
    node = TreeNode(0)
    head = node
    q = collections.deque([(node, 0, l)])
    while q:
        node, left, right = q.popleft()
        mid = (right + left) // 2
        node.val = nums[mid]
        if left < mid:
            node.left = TreeNode(0)
            q.append((node.left, left, mid))
        if mid < right-1:
            node.right = TreeNode(0)
            q.append((node.right, mid+1, right))
    return head
```

They are implemented using deque. Notice popleft() returns the first element(like stack) and pop() returns the last element(like queue).

Comment: In one stack method deque is not necessary. Since only append() and pop() are used, regular python list would be enough and still effective.

Answer (score 0):

> This problem is mostly due to me not understanding the way the normal
>   recursive method words, although when looking at them side by side to
>   see how to approach it, I always get stuck on what to do.

It takes practice ... and maybe reviewing other peoples work.

> require two stacks (to contain a left_Index and right_Index).

My apologies, I do not understand why the OP thinks this. My demo below has only 1 stack called 'todo', perhaps you will find the idea useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

#include "./BTree.hh"  // code not provided, used in this MCVE to 
                       // conveniently provide "showTallTreeView()" 

typedef std::vector<int>  IVec_t;  

class T607_t
{
   IVec_t m_sortedIVec;    // sorted - created with for loop
   IVec_t m_recursiveIVec; // extract from sorted by recursion
   IVec_t m_iterativeIVec; // extract from sorted by iteration

public:

   T607_t() = default;
   ~T607_t() = default;

   int exec(int , char**  )
      {
         fillShowSortedIVec();

         fillShowRecursiveIVec();

         fillShowIterativeIVec();

         showResults();

         return 0;
      }

private: // methods
```

The vectors are in class T607_t, so that each is available to any member function.

For this MCVE, I simply create "IVec_t m_sortedIVec;" and fill with a simple for loop:

```
   void fillShowSortedIVec()
      {
         for (int i=0; i<15; ++i)
            m_sortedIVec.push_back (i*100);  // create in sorted order

         showIVec(m_sortedIVec, "\n  m_sortedIVec   :");   
      }
```

Next (in this MCVE) is the recursive fill and show, and my adaptation of the OP's recursive method to produce the recursive insert sequence:

```
   // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   void fillShowRecursiveIVec()
      {
         assert(m_sortedIVec.size() > 0);
         int max = static_cast<int>(m_sortedIVec.size()) - 1;

         // use OP's recursive insert
         array2balancedR (m_sortedIVec, 0, max);  
         // NOTE - 'sequence' is inserted to 'm_recursiveIVec'
         //        instead of into tree the op did not share

         showIVec(m_recursiveIVec, "\n  m_recursiveIVec:");
      }

   // recursive extract from: m_sortedIVec  to: m_recursiveIVec
   // my adaptation of OP's recursive method
   void array2balancedR(IVec_t& array, int lIndex, int rIndex)
      {
         //base case
         if(lIndex > rIndex)
         {
            return;
         }
         else    //recursive calls
         {
            int mid = (lIndex+rIndex)/2;
            m_recursiveIVec.push_back(array[mid]);  // does this
            // tree.insert(array[mid]);             // instead of this

            array2balancedR(array, lIndex, mid-1);  // recurse left
            array2balancedR(array, mid+1, rIndex);  // recurse right
         }
      }
```

Note: I left the "IVec_t& array" as a parameter to this function, because the OP's code has it.  Within this 'class' wrapper, the function need not pass the array 'through the recursion', because each method has access to the instance data.

Next (in this MCVE) is a fill and show action using one possible iterative approach.  I styled this iterative approach carefully to match the OP's recursive effort.

First, I added a 'tool' (IndxRng_t) to simplify the 'stack' capture of iterations for later processing.  (i.e. "todo").

```
   // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // iterative extract from  m_sortedIVec  to: m_iterativeIVec
   class IndxRng_t  // tool to simplify iteration
   {
   public:
      IndxRng_t() = delete; // no default
      IndxRng_t(int li, int ri)
         : lIndx (li)
         , rIndx (ri)
         {}
      ~IndxRng_t() = default;

      // get'er and set'er free.  also glutton free.  gmo free.
      bool            done() { return (lIndx > rIndx); } // range used up
      int              mid() { return ((lIndx + rIndx) / 2); } // compute
      IndxRng_t   left(int m) { return {lIndx, m-1}; }  // ctor
      IndxRng_t  right(int m) { return {m+1, rIndx}; }  // ctor
   private:
      int lIndx;
      int rIndx;
   };


   void fillShowIterativeIVec()
      {
         assert(m_sortedIVec.size() > 0);
         int max = static_cast<int>(m_sortedIVec.size()) - 1;

         array2balancedI(m_sortedIVec, 0, max); 
         // 'sequence' inserted to 'm_iterativeIVec'

         showIVec(m_iterativeIVec, "\n  m_iterativeIVec:");
      }


   void array2balancedI(IVec_t& array, int lIndex, int rIndex)
      {
         std::vector<IndxRng_t>  todo;
         todo.push_back({lIndex, rIndex}); // load the first range

         // iterative loop (No recursion)
         do
         {
            if (0 == todo.size()) break; // exit constraint
            // no more ranges to extract mid from

            // fetch something to do
            IndxRng_t  todoRng = todo.back();
            todo.pop_back(); // and remove from the todo list

            if(todoRng.done()) continue; // lIndex > rIndex 

            int mid = todoRng.mid();
            m_iterativeIVec.push_back(array[mid]);  // do this
            // tree.insert(array[mid]);             // instead of this

            todo.push_back(todoRng.right(mid) ); // iterate on right
            todo.push_back(todoRng.left(mid)  ); // iterate on left

         }while(1);
      }
```

And this mcve generates a result display:

```
   void showResults()
      {
         assert(m_recursiveIVec.size() == m_sortedIVec.size());
         assert(m_iterativeIVec.size() == m_sortedIVec.size());

         std::cout << std::endl;

         std::stringstream ss; // for btree use only

         std::cout << "\n  demo:\n     create a BTree, "
                   << std::flush;
         std::cout << "\n     Insert IVec_t " << std::endl;

         BBT::BTree_t btree(ss);
         std::cout << std::flush;

         for (size_t i=0; i<m_iterativeIVec.size(); ++i)
            btree.insertPL(m_iterativeIVec[i]);

         std::cout << "\n iterative result:\n\n" 
                   << btree.showTallTreeView();
      }


   void showIVec(IVec_t& ivec, std::string lbl)
   {
      std::cout << lbl << std::endl;
      for (auto it : ivec)
         std::cout << std::setw(5) << it << std::flush;
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }

}; // class T607_t


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   T607_t  t607;
   return  t607.exec(argc, argv);
}
```

My output (on Ubuntu 17.10, g++ 7.2.0),

```
  m_sortedIVec   :
    0  100  200  300  400  500  600  700  800  900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400

  m_recursiveIVec:
  700  300  100    0  200  500  400  600 1100  900  800 1000 1300 1200 1400

  m_iterativeIVec:
  700  300  100    0  200  500  400  600 1100  900  800 1000 1300 1200 1400


  demo:
     create a BTree, 
     Insert IVec_t 

 iterative result:

  BTree_t::showTallTreeView():  (balance: 0  sz: 15)

                     0 
               100 
                    200 
          300 
                    400 
               500 
                    600 
     700 
                    800 
               900 
                    1000 
          1100 
                    1200 
               1300 
                    1400 

-----------------
```

Comment: showTallTreeView() displays the tree on its side ... with top to the left.

Answer (score 0):

**Iterative JavaScript implementation of converting sorted array to Binary Search Tree (BST):**

```js
function sortedArrayToBstIteratively(nums) {
    // use stack to iteratively split nums into node tuples and reuse values
    const stack = []

    // add root node to tree
    const tree = { first: 0, last: nums.length - 1 }
    stack.push(tree)

    // split array in the middle and continue with the two halfs
    while (stack.length > 0) {
        const node = stack.pop()

        if (node.last >= node.first) {
            if (node.last === node.first) {
                // node reaches a single leaf value (last == first)
                node.value = nums[node.first]
            } else {
                // node has still valid indices to further split the array (last > first)
                const middle = Math.ceil((node.first + node.last) / 2)
                node.value = nums[middle]
                node.left = { first: node.first, last: middle - 1 }
                node.right = { first: middle + 1, last: node.last }
                stack.push(node.left)
                stack.push(node.right)
            }
        } else {
            // node has no more valid indices (last < first), create empty leaf
            node.value = null
        }

        delete node.first
        delete node.last
    }

    // console.log(JSON.stringify(tree))

    return tree
}
```